# Is there a way to remove numbers in a list dependant on conditions of previous number?

Tags: python, list

I am looking to remove numbers from `mylist` and need to code something that will do this:

1. Take a look at the first element and remove all other elements in the list that are an increment above and an increment below
2. Your list is now smaller, look at the 2nd element in the list and remove all other elements that again are an increment above and an increment below.
3. Carry on until the end of the list, until you are left with survivors of the purge!

---

#### Example 1

`mylist = [1,8,9,3,5,6,2,4]`

`increment = 1`

**Desired Output:**

```
[1,8,9,3,5,6,4] # number in list observed - 1, removes these numbers in the list: 0 & 2

[1,8,3,5,6,4]   # number in list observed - 8, removes these numbers in the list: 7 & 9

[1,8,3,5,6]     # number in list observed - 3, removes these numbers in the list: 2 & 4

[1,8,3,5]       # number in list observed - 5, removes these numbers in the
```

`list: 4 & 6`

#### Example 2

`mylist = [1,8,9,3,5,6,2,4]`

`increment = 2`

**Desired Output:**

```
[1,8,9,5,6,4]  # number in list observed - 1, removes these numbers in the list: -1,0,2,3  

[1,8,5,4]      # number in list observed - 8, removes these numbers in the list: 6,7,9,10  

[1,8,5]        # number in list observed - 5, removes these numbers in the
```

`list: 3,4,6,7`

---

This has been difficult for me to figure out because the numbers in the list that need to be removed are very far from the number observed. I am working with lists of 675,000 numbers long and need to shred off numbers that I don't need, within an increment of 1098.

Comment: **Your list is now smaller, look at the 2nd**, no the list may not be smaller or in another case the array index may be invalid due to shorter length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First step is to find out exactly what needs to be removed, in a linear scan:

```
li = [1,8,9,3,5,6,2,4]
increment = 1

to_remove = set()
for x in li:
    if x not in to_remove:
        # Number is not going to be removed by previous numbers,
        # so it's going to be the next purge candidate.
        for i in range(1, 1 + increment):
            to_remove.add(x - i)
            to_remove.add(x + i)
```

And then to simply purge:

```
purged_li = [x for x in li if x not in to_remove]
```

This has worst case complexity `O(nk log(nk))` where `n == len(li)` and `k == increment`. You can do better but it going to involve much more complex range query data structures.

Comment: Thanks a lot mate! The script I am working on scans for a pattern on stock prices  and returns a list of best matches however the list contains repeats and overlaps of the same pattern so i wanted to filter out the overlaps and repeats. You really helped me out here :)